# Error Unable to get property 'getEnumerator' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Getting the following error when running my script:

```
Unable to get property 'getEnumerator' of undefined or null reference
```

My code :

```
NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove = (function () {

    var collListItems;
    removemessage = function (getid) {

        NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Community/News-and-feedback/Feedback';
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Feedback Items');

        var querystring = jQuery('#createdby').text();

        for (var i = 0; i < getid.length; i++) {


            getid[i] = getid[i].substring(getid[i].lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
            getid[i] = Math.round(getid[i]);

        }

        if (getid.length != 0) {
            var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Text'>" + querystring + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
            collListItems = oList.getItems(query);


            clientContext.load(collListItems, 'Include(Title, ID,IsDeleted,RequireFeedback)');

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        }

    }
    onQuerySucceeded = function () {
        var itemTitle = [];
        var sentnumber = 0;
        var inboxnumber = 0;

        var listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback = collListItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.moveNext()) {

            feedbackListItem = listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.get_current();

            if (feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Sent' || feedbackListItem.get_item('RequireFeedback') == false || feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Both') {
                jQuery("div[title='" + (feedbackListItem.get_item('Title')) + "sent']").parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');

                var sentlength = jQuery('.nbsallmessagecountsent').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;


                jQuery("#nbsmessagesentcount").text('Showing ' + sentlength + ' of ' + sentlength + ' conversations');
                if (sentlength <= 0) {
                    jQuery('#sentcounters').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#sentcounters').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                }



            }

            if (feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Inbox' || feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Both') {

                jQuery("div[title='" + (feedbackListItem.get_item('Title')) + "inbox']").parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
                var inboxlength = jQuery('.allmessagecount').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;
                jQuery("#nbsmessageinboxcount").text('Showing ' + inboxlength + ' of ' + inboxlength + ' conversations');

                if (inboxlength == 0) {
                    jQuery('#nbsnewmessages').text('');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#nbsnewmessages').text('(' + inboxlength + ')');
                }
                if (inboxlength <= 0) {
                    jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                }

            }
        }

    }

    onQueryFailed = function (sender, args) {

    }

    return {
        removemessage: removemessage
    }

})()
```

And I call it using `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js","SP.ClientContext",someSimpleWrapper);`

Comment: You are using executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded wrong there, thats the syntax for SP.SOD.execute() . This is the right syntax: SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName);  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change `var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();` to `var query = new SP.CamlQuery();`

Comment: nope doesn't work

Comment: Try removing `<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>` to `<View>`. Please confirm the item you are searching actually returns results.

Comment: it was working fine until I added the SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js","SP.ClientContext",someSimpleWrapper); to sort out another bug